# Select (highlight) content of TextBox on click

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using the latest version of ASP.net MVC, I'm trying to attach an event listener to a TextBox to highlight the content of the TextBox when clicked.

I thought this simple JQuery would work:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.item1, new { onclick= "$(this).blur();" })
```

But when I click on the TextBox, it just loses focus right away without leaving any errors in the browser's console.

I've also tried JQuery's `onfocus` and `onmouseup` events without success.

How can I highlight the content of the TextBox when it is clicked?

Comment: .blur is called when elements lose their focus so i think your code is creating an error by wrongly using methods

Comment: what you did is, onclick(this gives the element focus) $(this).blur() when the clicked object has no focus anymore do nothing, since you don't call a function inside your () from .blur()

Comment: Wait... blur or Highlight ? I want the text to be selected in blue

Comment: the text color of the selected text must be blue or the outline around the text should be blue?

Comment: Just when you slide mouse over text when holding mouse left button... So the text is ready to be copied

Comment: ohhh this is what you mean: https://css-tricks.com/examples/DifferentSelectionColors/ ?

Comment: Yes i want the whole textbox's text to be highlighted on click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select all the text in the selected textbox onclick,

this would be the code: `@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.item1, new { onclick= "$(this).select();" })`

Comment: This is what I was looking for but I was too dumb to realize that Blur didn't mean Select

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer,im glad we found out you ment select and not blur ;)

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with your code. There is no problem with the actual behavior you are getting.
Read the documentation [jQuery Blur method documentation](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)

> Bind an event handler to the "blur" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Now read the [JavaScript blur event documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp)

> The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus.

So, basically, in your example you are saying that your component should lose focus when clicked, which is exactly what is happening

If what you want is to visually ***blur*** your element then you can try something like this

```css
.blurred{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
div{
  width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- If what you want is to blur the element -->
<input type="text" value="click me to blur me" onclick="$(this).addClass('blurred')"/>

<hr/>

<!-- If what you want is to select all the content -->
<input type="text" value="click me to select all the data" onclick="$(this).select()"/>
```

Comment: At this point i don't know what to do... I was talking about select... not blur. My translation mistake.

Comment: Please, edit your question title to better reflect your problem

Answer (score 2):

As I understand "blur" in terms of u, is text color should be changed to light grey.

It can be done simply by :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.item1, new { onclick= "$(this).css('color','#ddd');" })
```